# Создал свой сайт, получилось всё смещённо на других разрешениях монитора

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h3>Калькулятор возраста</h3>
        <div id="buttons_div">
            <button id="btn">Активировать</button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <square id="square-mdm">
            <div id="square-type">
                <h1>Мои другие проекты</h1>
                <button id="page" onclick="document.location='page.html'">Генератор чисел</button>
                <button id="page3" onclick="document.location='zodiac.html'">Калькулятор Зодиака</button>
                <button id="page1" onclick="document.location='clicker.html'">Кликер</button>
                <h2>Создатель сайта N1xsane</h2>
            </div>
        </square>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="p1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 980px;
}
body {
    background-color: white;
}
#square-type {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 70px;
    z-index: 999; 
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 15px;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; */
    background-color: #E4FBFF;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
main {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 15px;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; */
    background-color: #E4FBFF;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    color: darkgray;
}
button {
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; */
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 50px 100px;
    /* margin-top: 50px; */
    padding: 15px 32px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
#page {
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; */
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 15px 32px;
    /* margin-top: 50px; */
    padding: 15px 32px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #4c53af;
}
#page1 {
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; */
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 15px 32px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #4c53af;   
}
#page3 {
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; */
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 15px 32px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #4c53af;   
}
```

Comment: Вам нудно адаптировать сайт под  другие разрешения (планшеты, телефоны). Ознакомьтесь с меди запросами @media

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.